# Order by a VIEW list of user_ids

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a VIEW that keeps track of how a specific user (author) interacts with other users (receiever). See VIEW:

[image: the table]

Here you can see how AUTHOR (the user_id) interacts with the other users by posting on his wall (post), liking their stuff (like) and also follows. Is there a way I can order the table POSTS with this VIEW? What I'd like to achieve is to show the wall posts (table: posts) and move the most relevant posts (the posts where the reciever ID appear most).

The posts table looks like this:

[image: posts table]

I'd like to order the post_author (from above table) against receiver (in the view).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You have to bulid a variable wich contains all ID's in correct order nad put them into `field()` function

```
ORDER BY FIELD(ID, (id's to order by))
```

EDIT:
Here is tutorial:
http://www.imthi.com/blog/programming/mysql-order-by-field-custom-field-sorting.php

Comment: Nice! What if I also want to sort by date? I want the newest post as possible, or well; as long as we dont get 2 months old posts

Comment: i don't know the stucture, and desired output as You want, but Yes, by date as well. 2 months posts You can limit in `where`condition

Comment: You can provide query, if You would have any problem i will help You.

Comment: The [query looks like this](http://pastebin.com/edZBYhdS). It is actually working on the sorting part (the order by at the end, is based on the VIEW i told about). However, the issue is now, that it will simply just throw ALL the user_id 3's posts in the top. I need some kind of sort, so it isin't completly in the top. Any ideas?

Comment: ORDER BY post_date, FIELD(p.post_author,3,2,33) DESC ??